# strange behavior jsonwebtoken expired error

Tags: node.js, jwt

I have a Node.js application which uses jsonwebtoken for session management.

However, after the token expired, when I want to access again, I got:

```
{ TokenExpiredError: jwt expired
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (/home/ubuntu/me-n-you/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:126:19)
    at auth (/home/ubuntu/me-n-you/app_server/routes/index.js:14:9)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/me-n-you/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/ubuntu/me-n-you/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/ubuntu/me-n-you/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/me-n-you/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/ubuntu/me-n-you/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/ubuntu/me-n-you/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/ubuntu/me-n-you/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/home/ubuntu/me-n-you/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/home/ubuntu/me-n-you/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/me-n-you/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/ubuntu/me-n-you/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/ubuntu/me-n-you/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/ubuntu/me-n-you/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/ubuntu/me-n-you/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
  name: 'TokenExpiredError',
  message: 'jwt expired',
  expiredAt: 2018-05-08T21:14:27.000Z }
```

I repeat to get the same errors until a very long time then I could access again.

But, I can access if using another device or browser at the same time.

I have no idea how to fix it. Does anyone have any clue on this?

Thanks in advance.

Richard Xu

Answer (score 0):

You can again logged in ,also if you are using bcrypt

```
bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, data[0].password, (err, resposne) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).json(err);
            }
            //response is either true or false
            if (resposne) {
                const token = jwt.sign({
                    email: data[0].email,
                    userId: data[0]._id
                }, "secret",
                    {
                          expiresIn: "1h"
                    })
                return res.status(200).json({
                    message: 'Auth successful',
                    token: token
                })
            } else {
                return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Auth failed' })
            }
        })
```

Increase your expiry limit

Comment: I am using passport module.